# Is the usage of livedata-ktx with ViewModels causing memory leaks if the LiveData is not backed by a property?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Using `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` and `lifecycle-livedata-ktx` and given the following example:

**ViewModel implementation:**

```
class AutocompletionViewModel: ViewModel() {

    fun getAutocompletion(inputString: CharSequence?) = liveData {
        delay(10)
        emit("$inputString DUMMY AUTOCOMPLETION")
    }
}
```

**Fragment part**:

```
val viewModel by viewModels<AutocompletionViewModel>()
/* Acquiring EditText*/
editText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{

    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
        viewModel.getAutocompletion(editable).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { editable?.append(it) })
    }

    /* Other TextWatcher method implementations*/
})
```

**Would this code cause a memory leak if the user types text into the EditText?**

I assume that with every text change a new `LiveData` object with a stong referenced `Observer` is created (and will be alive until the fragment is destroyed). <s>Nevertheless, a similar example **was** shown by the official docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata</s>

Comment: `LiveData` is lifecycle aware. They are gone when the `Fragment` is gone.

Comment: Yes, I know, read my comment in parentheses. To clarify: I want to know if this code would end in an OutOfMemoryException if I type enough text into the EditText, because it creates more and more LiveData instances with strong referenced Observers which could not be garbage collected.

Comment: I doubt if you even need `LiveData` for that. What's the point? Sending text to the `ViewModel` and receiving it back?

Comment: It is an minimal example, reduced to the essence. I don't want to clutter the getAutocompletion function with real HTTP request logic and response parsing. (BTW This is a typical procedure when asking questions at StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, there is memory leak:** 
I attached Android Studios memory profiler and executed `AutocompletionViewModel.getAutocompletion` 10 thousand times. Regardless of a garbage collection, `Observer` and `LiveData` objects remain still in memory: 
[image]

**Conclusion for this case**: `LiveData` object should be backed by a property and `Observers` should only be attached once

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it a memory leak, you can call it a bad design or disadvantage of this pattern.

But it's not a type of memory leaks.

Memory leak could happened with following actions:

Assign an activity or fragment or listener reference in application lifecycle or static 'companion' object or singleton.

for more info check this [article](https://proandroiddev.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-memory-leaks-in-android-d7a59faaf46a)

Comment: Read the correct answer and read the definition on Wikipedia: "In computer science, a memory leak is a type of resource leak that occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations[1] in a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released."